# Using wildcard with mysqlimport on Windows 7

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line, wildcard

I'm trying to upload multiple files into an existing database with an empty tables. I use the fallowing code in the windows command line:

```
mysqlimport --fields_escaped_by=\\ mydb -L *.txt
```

the output is:

```
Error 1017, Can't find file: '.\mydb\@002a.frm' (errno: 22), when using table: *
```

I used this command to execute on CentOS with no problems, but windows makes it difficult to import multiple txt files (single file no problem). I used system variables to define default user and password. Also I execute in the directory where the text files are in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cmd.exe doesn't filename expansion as shells like bash do.

You could i.e. use for, see `help for`:

```
for %f in (*.txt) do mysqlimport --fields_escaped_by=\\ mydb -L %f
```

That will execute mysqlimport for each file (not once for the list of files).